# Multiple Rscript execution increase memory

Tags: c#, cmd, rodbc, rscript

I am  executing in parallel multiple cmd windows to run rscript.exe. In the R script i am doing paralel ODBC connections to SQL to read 1 million of entries per script (migration procedure).

It looks like every rscript.exe increase the memory exponencially, i have running 70 scripts in parallel consuming from 5Mb of RAM to 700Mb
[see attached imge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFkFA.png)

I am specting every script consuming the same memory.

Did you experience something similar?
thanks

Comment: Are you seriously telling us that a memory increase when running several instances of the same executable at the same time, whilst each of those, is in turn running several processes at the same time, is unexpected behavior?

Comment: yes, may  be i explained wrongly, let me try again (see screenshot): first process consumes 5MB, second process consumes 15Mb (5 + 10), third process consumes 30Mb (5 + 10 + 15) ..... Process number 70 consumes more than 700Mb. Again, it is only a ODBC connection to read only 1 Million of entries for each proceess